# view frame width is not correct after layoutSubViews, against its constraints on offcial iOS 9

Tags: ios, autolayout

I am testing my app on official iOS 9 with Xcode 7 as well.

I am able to reproduce it with a simple demo project:

https://github.com/liuxuan30/autolayoutProblemOniOS9

My app works great on iOS 7 & 8, but when I run it on iOS 9, some of the UILabel's frame width is not consistent with its contraints:

This is how I set up my layout, it's quite simple, there are two Labels in the UICollectionViewCell.xib, and align leading and trailing as the cell, and a fixed height and top margin.

Top label:

[image]

Bottom label:

[image]

However, at run time,

When I add a break point at UICollectionViewCell's layoutSubViews like:

```
-(void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews]; // break here
}
```

After calling `[super layoutSubViews]` the topLabel's frame is different from its constraints:

```
// before [super layoutSubViews]
(lldb) po self.topLabel
<UILabel: 0x7fc636ff6450; frame = (0 15; 90 21); text = '本周市场份额'; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <_UILabelLayer: 0x7fc636ff6650>>

(lldb) po self.topLabel.constraints
<__NSArrayI 0x7fc6371cf9e0>(
<NSContentSizeLayoutConstraint:0x7fc637300960 H:[UILabel:0x7fc636ff6450'本周市场份额'(90)] Hug:250 CompressionResistance:750>,
<NSContentSizeLayoutConstraint:0x7fc637301d80 V:[UILabel:0x7fc636ff6450'本周市场份额'(18)] Hug:250 CompressionResistance:750>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fc636ff6d10 V:[UILabel:0x7fc636ff6450'本周市场份额'(18)]>
)

// after [super layoutSubViews]
(lldb) po self.topLabel
<UILabel: 0x7fc636ff6450; frame = (0 15; 64 18); text = '本周市场份额'; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <_UILabelLayer: 0x7fc636ff6650>>
```

The width is wrong, it should be 90, but actually it is 64 after [super layoutSubViews]. It only happens on iOS 9, which confuses me. Please help!

Edit: Here's the UICollectionViewCell's frame info and constraints before/after [super layoutSubViews]:

```
// before [super layoutSubViews]
(lldb) po self
<BDPDetailCollectionViewCell: 0x7fbe55505a50; baseClass = UICollectionViewCell; frame = (0 0; 90 64); clipsToBounds = YES; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fbe55505eb0>>

(lldb) po self.constraints
<__NSArrayI 0x7fbe55458940>(
<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7fbe5550cd30 h=--& v=--& UIView:0x7fbe555060e0.midX == + 45>,
<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7fbe5550cd80 h=--& v=--& H:[UIView:0x7fbe555060e0(90)]>,
<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7fbe5550cdd0 h=--& v=--& UIView:0x7fbe555060e0.midY == + 32>,
<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7fbe5550b850 h=--& v=--& V:[UIView:0x7fbe555060e0(64)]>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fbe555080d0 UIView:0x7fbe555060e0.trailing == UILabel:0x7fbe55506dd0'17.06'.trailing>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fbe55508120 UILabel:0x7fbe55506dd0'17.06'.leading == UIView:0x7fbe555060e0.leading>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fbe55508170 UILabel:0x7fbe55506dd0'17.06'.top == UIView:0x7fbe555060e0.top + 38>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fbe555081c0 UILabel:0x7fbe55507a40'本周市场份额'.leading == UIView:0x7fbe555060e0.leading>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fbe55508210 UIView:0x7fbe555060e0.trailing == UILabel:0x7fbe55507a40'本周市场份额'.trailing>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fbe55508260 UILabel:0x7fbe55507a40'本周市场份额'.top == UIView:0x7fbe555060e0.top + 15>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fbe5550c6e0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' V:[BDPDetailCollectionViewCell:0x7fbe55505a50(64)]>,
<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7fbe5550cad0 h=--& v=--& 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Left' H:|-(0)-[BDPDetailCollectionViewCell:0x7fbe55505a50]   (Names: '|':UICollectionView:0x7fbe538a0600 )>,
<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7fbe5550cb20 h=--& v=--& 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Top' V:|-(0)-[BDPDetailCollectionViewCell:0x7fbe55505a50]   (Names: '|':UICollectionView:0x7fbe538a0600 )>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fbe5550c690 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' H:[BDPDetailCollectionViewCell:0x7fbe55505a50(90)]>
)

// After [super layoutSubViews]
(lldb) po self
<BDPDetailCollectionViewCell: 0x7fbe55505a50; baseClass = UICollectionViewCell; frame = (0 0; 90 64); clipsToBounds = YES; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fbe55505eb0>>

(lldb) po self.constraints
<__NSArrayI 0x7fbe550495e0>(
<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7fbe5550cd30 h=--& v=--& UIView:0x7fbe555060e0.midX == + 45>,
<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7fbe5550cd80 h=--& v=--& H:[UIView:0x7fbe555060e0(90)]>,
<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7fbe5550cdd0 h=--& v=--& UIView:0x7fbe555060e0.midY == + 32>,
<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7fbe5550b850 h=--& v=--& V:[UIView:0x7fbe555060e0(64)]>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fbe555080d0 UIView:0x7fbe555060e0.trailing == UILabel:0x7fbe55506dd0'17.06'.trailing>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fbe55508120 UILabel:0x7fbe55506dd0'17.06'.leading == UIView:0x7fbe555060e0.leading>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fbe55508170 UILabel:0x7fbe55506dd0'17.06'.top == UIView:0x7fbe555060e0.top + 38>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fbe555081c0 UILabel:0x7fbe55507a40'本周市场份额'.leading == UIView:0x7fbe555060e0.leading>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fbe55508210 UIView:0x7fbe555060e0.trailing == UILabel:0x7fbe55507a40'本周市场份额'.trailing>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fbe55508260 UILabel:0x7fbe55507a40'本周市场份额'.top == UIView:0x7fbe555060e0.top + 15>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fbe5550c6e0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' V:[BDPDetailCollectionViewCell:0x7fbe55505a50(64)]>,
<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7fbe5550cad0 h=--& v=--& 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Left' H:|-(0)-[BDPDetailCollectionViewCell:0x7fbe55505a50]   (Names: '|':UICollectionView:0x7fbe538a0600 )>,
<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7fbe5550cb20 h=--& v=--& 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Top' V:|-(0)-[BDPDetailCollectionViewCell:0x7fbe55505a50]   (Names: '|':UICollectionView:0x7fbe538a0600 )>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fbe5550c690 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' H:[BDPDetailCollectionViewCell:0x7fbe55505a50(90)]>
)
```

Update: add a screenshot with reveal:

[image]

Comment: I ran your sample project on Xcode 7 GM on iOS 9.0 and 9.1. The width of the label was 90 for both.

Comment: I am able to reproduce on Xcode 7 GM (7A218) + iOS 9 13A340. Per our previous talk in another deleted thread, you are on on 7.1 beta (I thought I was GM). iOS simulator on that and my phone is iOS 9.1. If you have  Xcode 7 GM (7A218) + iOS 9 13A340, you can have a try. thanks for help!

Comment: @Fogmeister I downloaded Xcode 7.1 Beta 7B60 today, with iOS 9.1 13B5110e, I am still able to reproduce it with the demo project... I am truly confused now.

Comment: Set a background colour on the cell. Is the cell the correct size?

Comment: Yes, the cell is the correct size. Only the label width is not as constraints

Comment: @Fogmeister I have uploaded a screenshot with yellow background color for cell. You will see the constraints, frame data and the visual in it.

Comment: well I can't really help because I can't replicate the problem you are having.

Comment: @Fogmeister feels bad man. I can only hope tomorrow it will be OK

Comment: @Fogmeister now I am with Official Xcode 7 7A220, and iOS 13A344 on real device, 13A340 on simulator, still able to reproduce. I have updated my demo project, https://github.com/liuxuan30/autolayoutProblemOniOS9, could you please try again? Thanks.

Comment: @Fogmeister, hey man, I think I fount the reason. In the cell xib, the cell size is 64*64 right now. But at run time, I give the size 90*64 by delegate, but it continues using 64*64 size to layout my Labels, not 90 * 64. If I change it to 84*64 on xib, it actually set the label width as 84. Now the problem is, how to get rid of this 'design time size'